# extjs grid filter example not loading data

Tags: extjs, filter, grid

I'm attempting to learn a bit more about out how grid filtering works in Extjs.

I'm using the example that comes with the JS 4 download, i.e.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html

I can run it on my local server such that it displays the grid outline (with filter options in the column headers), but no data gets loaded at all. I was hoping that I could just use the local flag with the accompanying JSON file without the need to get involved with the SQLlite aspects, for a start.

I can't figure out why the JSON data isn't loading though. Any help, hints or tips would be much appreciated. I've spent ages on this, looking at other examples, both via here, Google and the Sencha website.

Comment: I can't see any in the Firebug console. I first get the page with just the static text, then after a short while, the grid appears, with a "loading" text, that disappears but the grid cells are empty. The column headers are as per the Sencha example.

Comment: On your local machine have you got a copy of the json file grid-filter.json? Copy of it is here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/extjs-build/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter.json

Comment: Yes, I do already have that, unfortunately. I did check the path, but am about to double check again, as the symptoms do imply that it simply can't find teh data?

Comment: I have finally managed to get local data displaying by moving the whole application into another directory, and resetting the paths. I still can't spot why the original didn't work, but have something to work with now. Many thanks to Amalea for trying to help.

Comment: That is a little strange, unless it was a permissions problem on the original directory maybe? Sorry I couldn't be more help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark as complete (see above) though I don't know detail on why it's started working.